# Android Shell edited file isn't recognized by app anymore

Tags: android, shell, adb, root, preferences

First-time poster here, I apologize for any mistakes. :) I searched for quite the while on this problem but could't find anything.

I am trying to edit a shared_preferences-file of another android application. (I have the developer's permission to do so.) The file is an xml structured like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
    <string name="password">XYZ</string>
    <string name="username">XYZ</string>
    <boolean name="2.6.0.5" value="false" />
    <boolean name="disclaimer.isAccepted" value="true" />
    <string  name="safeForMode2">7</string>
</map>
```

I load the file with a root-terminal, edit the content and write it back to the file.

Loading code:

```
String[] commands = {"cd <directory>", "cat pref-file.xml"};  
String output = RunAsRoot(commands);
settings = output;
```

Writing code:

```
String[] commands = {"cd <directory>", "echo '" + settings + "' > pref-file.xml"};
RunAsRoot(commands);
```

RunAsRoot gets SU-Privilieges and executes the commands in the String-Array. This part works fine.

If I edit the file using e.g. ES File Explorer, everything works fine. The settings are applied and it works. If I try to edit it with above code, the modified file isn't recognized by the app and will be overwritten with it's standard-xml, resulting in a complete reset of the app's settings.

I already checked the file-permissions and set them identical to the source-file, but the app won't accept it. In the text-editor both versions of the file look exactly the same.

Do you experienced this issue somewhere before? As it seems, both files are identical to each other. I can't find the reason why the app won't accept it. If you need more codesnippets, I'll be glad to post them.

Again, apologies if this question has been answered before. In this case I would be very happy to get a link. ;)

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Fixed a mistake in the xml-example. Header weren't included.

Comment: Just guessing here, but does it have anything to do with encoding? The edited XML file would most likely need to be encoded as UTF-8 for it to be recognized.

Comment: @JASONGPETERSON: ES File Explorer shows that both versions are UTF-8-encoded. :/

Comment: Use `chown` to restore file's ownership info

Comment: File owner and permissions are read from the file before the edit and set again after the write process. As I said - everything looks identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use awk to alter the file content and writing it back using dd:

```
awk '/map/{print " <string name=\"foo\">"}1 | dd of=/path/to/xml
```

This keeps the original file but exchanges the whole content.

Comment: THANKS, that solved my issue. Look at my answer for the full code. :)

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to kuhno I was able to resolve the issue. I used his solution to add the setting to the bottom of the file:

```
public void AddSetting(int value) throws Throwable {
    // Change directory, insert Setting in XML and write changes back to file
    String[] commands = {
            "cd <directory>",
            "awk '/\\/map/{print \"    <string name=\\\"setting\\\">" + value + "</string>\"}1' pref-file.xml | dd of=pref-file.xml"
    };

    RunAsRoot(commands);
}
```

I'm changing the setting (if it's already existent) with "sed":

```
public void ChangeSetting(int value) throws Throwable {
    // Change directory, replace Setting in XML
    String[] commands = {
            "cd <directory>",
            "sed -i 's|<string name=\"setting\">.|<string name=\"setting\">" + value + "|' pref-file.xml"
    };

    RunAsRoot(commands);
}
```